# kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope is causing NullPointerException

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use Room MVVM architecture with retrofit my code: 
CurrentWeatherEntry data class is

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "humidity") var humidity: Double = 0.0,
    // @SerializedName("is_day") @ColumnInfo(name = "isDay") var isDay: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pressure") var pressure: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "temperature") var temperature: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("localtime_epoch") @ColumnInfo(name = "localtimeEpoch") var localtimeEpoch: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("weather_code") @ColumnInfo(name = "weatherCode") var weatherCode: Int = 0,
    // Ignore inserting list into table
    @Ignore @SerializedName("weather_descriptions")
    var weatherDescriptions: List<String> = emptyList(),
    // Just get first condition and it is good to go ;-)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var weatherDescription: String = weatherDescriptions[0],

    @SerializedName("wind_degree") @ColumnInfo(name = "windDegree") var windDegree: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("wind_dir") @ColumnInfo(name = "windDir") var windDir: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed") @ColumnInfo(name = "windSeep") var windSpeed: Double = 0.0,
    @SerializedName("feelslike") @ColumnInfo(name = "feelslike") var feelsLike: Double = 0.0
)  {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

Dao class is:

```
@Dao
interface CurrentWeatherDao {

    // Always there will be conflict because we only want to store current weather in db once
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsert(currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry): Unit

    @Query("SELECT * FROM current_weather WHERE id = $CURRENT_WEATHER_ID")
    fun getWeather(): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry>
}
```

ForecastRepository and ForecastRepositoryImpl classes are:

```
interface ForecastRepository {
    suspend fun getCurrentWeather(): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry>
}

class ForecastRepositoryImpl(
    private val currentWeatherDao: CurrentWeatherDao,
    private val weatherNetworkDataSource: WeatherNetworkDataSource
) : ForecastRepository {

    init {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.downloadedCurrentWeatherData.observeForever{newCurrentWeather ->
            // persist
            persistFetchedCurrentWeatherData(newCurrentWeather)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getCurrentWeather(): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            initWeatherData()
            return@withContext currentWeatherDao.getWeather()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initWeatherData() {
        if (isFetchCurrentNeeded(ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(1)))
            fetchCurrentWeather()
    }

    private suspend fun fetchCurrentWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentWeather("Sukkur")
    }

    private fun persistFetchedCurrentWeatherData(fetchedWeatherResponse: CurrentWeatherResponse) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            currentWeatherDao.upsert(fetchedWeatherResponse.currentWeatherEntry)
        }
    }

    private fun isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastFetchTime: ZonedDateTime): Boolean{
        val thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30)
        return lastFetchTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo)
    }
}
```

at this point on line `currentWeatherDao.upsert(fetchedWeatherResponse.currentWeatherEntry)` in persistFetchedCurrentWeatherData() it gives error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int app.weatherinfo.data.network.response.model.CurrentWeatherEntry.getId()' on a null object reference
        at app.weatherinfo.data.dao.CurrentWeatherDao_Impl$1.bind(CurrentWeatherDao_Impl.java:34)
        at app.weatherinfo.data.dao.CurrentWeatherDao_Impl$1.bind(CurrentWeatherDao_Impl.java:26)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:63)
        at app.weatherinfo.data.dao.CurrentWeatherDao_Impl.upsert(CurrentWeatherDao_Impl.java:58)
        at app.weatherinfo.data.repository.ForecastRepositoryImpl$persistFetchedCurrentWeatherData$1.invokeSuspend(ForecastRepositoryImpl.kt:44)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

As coroutines are new concept so I have searched a lot to resolve it but never resolved it.

Comment: Show you upsert methode from Data Access Object Interface.

Comment: `private suspend fun fetchCurrentWeather() { weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentWeather("Sukkur")
    }` --- this function has no return value? What does it do then?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik as I told I'm very new to Kotlin and coroutines and also I was following along a tutorial, so could not figure out What does it do then? any help please

Comment: You do not have column for primary key.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule there is indeed a `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID'

Comment: I am also using Kodein DI, does Kodein have a problem?

Comment: @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID This should be like this and add it to constructor

Comment: I have tried this but in vain...

Comment: Are you sure that your `fetchedWeatherResponse.currentWeatherEntry` is not null?

Comment: @r2rek I could not figure out, because coroutines with retrofit are totally new idea for me, I think  `fetchedWeatherResponse.currentWeatherEntry` is null for the most parts...

Comment: Add a httpinterceptor and read the response from logs. I assume your response is null :)